# "Error: Cannot find symbol class view" but import statement already exists

Tags: android-studio

I'm going through the getting started tutorial in the latest version of Android Studio (downloaded yesterday) and I've completed the sample app where you fill out a text field and click a button and display the text of that field in a new activity. Everything went smoothly until I went to run the app. I'm getting the error

> "Error: Cannot find symbol class view"

. Before you say I'm missing an import statement - I'm not. I've got import android.view.View in my MainActivity java file.

The import statement itself is grayed out and the tooltip for it reads "Unused import statement". Yet in my code, I don't see any red lines anywhere indicating that something is wrong.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(view View){
        // Do something in response to the button click
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMeS1.png)

Comment: [edit] the question and show the full error.

Comment: That is the full error. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: The error message should probably be added as text. One of the panels has the error you can copy and paste. Anyway, the error is very clear. Check your method signatures. Type names come before param names. Type names have initial caps in Java, and the param name does not.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going through the tutorial and re-building the project again from scratch. This time all worked well. I don't know what caused the problem in the original project, but I hope it wasn't corruption of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I guess it just happened maybe due to some broken indexing of the project. Here is how I resolved the issue:

In Android Studio Go to:

`File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`

It will restart the project with new indexing.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you passed a 'view' object as a parameter for your 'sendMessage' function that isn't declared:

```
public void sendMessage(view View){
```

Should be:

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
```

Because this way you are telling the compiler that you are going to pass a parameter called 'view', that is an instance of the 'View' class. Notice that you typed 'view View' instead of 'View view' so the compiler is looking for the lowercase 'view' class passed as parameter but it doesn't exist because in order to reference your actual import you need to type in the order I already mentioned.